# operator.index with custom class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I have a simple class below:

```
class MyClass(int):
    def __index__(self):
        return 1
```

According to [`operator.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.index) documentation:

> `operator.index(a)`
>
> Return *`a`* converted to an integer. Equivalent to `a.__index__()`

But when I use `operator.index` with `MyClass` instance, I got `100` instead of `1` (I am getting `1` if I use `a.__index__()`). Why is that?

```
>>> a = MyClass(100)
>>>
>>> import operator
>>> print(operator.index(a))
100
>>> print(a.__index__())
1
```

Comment: It only converts to integer if that's not already an integer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your type is an int subclass. `__index__` will not be used because the instance is already an integer. That much is by design, and unlikely to be considered a bug in CPython. PyPy behaves the same.

In [`_operator.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31729366e2bc09632e78f3896dbce0ae64914f28/Modules/_operator.c#L691-L696):

```c
static PyObject *
_operator_index(PyObject *module, PyObject *a)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=d972b0764ac305fc input=6f54d50ea64a579c]*/
{
    return PyNumber_Index(a);
}
```

Note that `operator.py` Python code is not used generally, this code is only a [fallback in the case that compiled `_operator` module is not available](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7c83eaa536d2f436ae46211ca48692f576c732f0/Lib/operator.py#L407-L410). That explains why the result `a.__index__()` differs.

In [`abstract.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Objects/abstract.c#L1246-L1289), cropped after the relevant `PyLong_Check` part:

```c
/* Return an exact Python int from the object item.
   Raise TypeError if the result is not an int
   or if the object cannot be interpreted as an index.
*/
PyObject *
PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = _PyNumber_Index(item);
    if (result != NULL && !PyLong_CheckExact(result)) {
        Py_SETREF(result, _PyLong_Copy((PyLongObject *)result));
    }
    return result;
}

...

/* Return a Python int from the object item.
   Can return an instance of int subclass.
   Raise TypeError if the result is not an int
   or if the object cannot be interpreted as an index.
*/
PyObject *
_PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    if (item == NULL) {
        return null_error();
    }

    if (PyLong_Check(item)) {
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;     /* <---- short-circuited here */
    }
    ...
}
```

The documentation for `operator.index` is inaccurate, so this may be considered a minor documentation issue:

```python
>>> import operator
>>> operator.index.__doc__
'Same as a.__index__()'
```

So, why isn't `__index__` considered for integers? The probable answer is found in [PEP 357](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/), under the discussion section titled [Speed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/#speed):

> Implementation should not slow down Python because integers and long integers used as indexes will complete in the same number of instructions. The only change will be that what used to generate an error will now be acceptable.

We do not want to slow down the most common case for slicing with integers, having to check for an `nb_index` slot every time.

Answer (score 6):

This actually appears to be a deep-rooted issue in cpython. If you [look at the source code for `operator.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7c83eaa536d2f436ae46211ca48692f576c732f0/Lib/operator.py), you can see the definition of `index`:

```py
def index(a):
    "Same as a.__index__()."
    return a.__index__()
```

So...why is it not equivalent? It's literally calling `__index__`. Well, at the bottom of the source, there's the culprit:

```py
try:
    from _operator import *
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    from _operator import __doc__
```

It's overwriting the definitions with a native `_operator` module. In fact, if you comment this out (either by modifying the actual library or making your own fake `operator.py`* and importing that), it works. So, [we can find the source code for the native `_operator` library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7c83eaa536d2f436ae46211ca48692f576c732f0/Modules/_operator.c#L691), and look at the related part:

```c
static PyObject *
_operator_index(PyObject *module, PyObject *a)
{
    return PyNumber_Index(a);
}
```

So, it's a wrapper around the `PyNumber_Index` function. `PyNumber_Index` is a wrapper around `_PyNumber_Index`, [so we can look at that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Objects/abstract.c#L1251):

```c
PyObject *
_PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    if (item == NULL) {
        return null_error();
    }

    if (PyLong_Check(item)) {
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;
    }
    if (!_PyIndex_Check(item)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "'%.200s' object cannot be interpreted "
                     "as an integer", Py_TYPE(item)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    result = Py_TYPE(item)->tp_as_number->nb_index(item);
    if (!result || PyLong_CheckExact(result))
        return result;
    if (!PyLong_Check(result)) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "__index__ returned non-int (type %.200s)",
                     Py_TYPE(result)->tp_name);
        Py_DECREF(result);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Issue #17576: warn if 'result' not of exact type int. */
    if (PyErr_WarnFormat(PyExc_DeprecationWarning, 1,
            "__index__ returned non-int (type %.200s).  "
            "The ability to return an instance of a strict subclass of int "
            "is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.",
            Py_TYPE(result)->tp_name)) {
        Py_DECREF(result);
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

PyObject *
PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = _PyNumber_Index(item);
    if (result != NULL && !PyLong_CheckExact(result)) {
        Py_SETREF(result, _PyLong_Copy((PyLongObject *)result));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can see before it even calls `nb_index` (the C name for `__index__`), it calls `PyLong_Check` on the argument, and if it's true, it just returns the item with no modification. [`PyLong_Check` is a macro that checks for long subtyping (`int` in python is a `PyLong`)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ace3f9a0ce7b9fe8ae757fdd614f1e7a171f92b0/Include/longobject.h#L14):

```c
#define PyLong_Check(op) \
        PyType_FastSubclass(Py_TYPE(op), Py_TPFLAGS_LONG_SUBCLASS)
#define PyLong_CheckExact(op) Py_IS_TYPE(op, &PyLong_Type)
```

So, basically, the takeaway is that for whatever reason, probably for speed, int subclasses don't get their `__index__`  method called, and instead just get `_PyLong_Copy`'d to the resulting return value, but only in the native `_operator` module, and not in the non-native `operator.py`. This conflict of implementation as well as inconsistency in documentation leads me to believe that this is an issue, either in the documentation or the implementation, and you may want to raise it as one.

It's likely a documentation and not an implementation issue, as cpython has a habit of sacrificing correctness for speed: `(nan,) == (nan,)` but `nan != nan`.

* You may have to name it something like `fake_operator.py` then import it with `import fake_operator as operator`

Comment: No offense, but this seems to be just duplicating the same info from my answer.

Comment: @wim ah yes, he duplicated your answer in 3 minutes

Comment: @wim Our answers are only 3 minutes apart, and I was already 3/4 way through writing my answer when you posted yours, and I didn't even notice until after I posted my answer. (If you don't want to take my word for it, then you should just think about how I could possibly read your answer then type up my whole answer in 3 minutes)

Comment: Hold up, I never claimed you read my answer first and then typed up your answer.  I just said that it duplicates the same info, so is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This answer is incorrect; I misread the documentation. See [Aplet123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65551787/4518341) instead. Tl;dr the problem is actually that the C implementation doesn't match the documentation and Python implementation. The C implementation is more like `a if isinstance(a, int) else a.__index__()`.

To prove it, try defining `MyClass.__int__()`. The outcome will be the same.

---

#### Original answer

See the documentation for [`object.__index__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__):

> `object.__index__(self)`
>
> Called to implement `operator.index()`, and whenever Python needs to losslessly convert the numeric object to an integer object (such as in slicing, or in the built-in `bin()`, `hex()` and `oct()` functions). Presence of this method indicates that the numeric object is an integer type. Must return an integer.
>
> **If [`__int__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__), [`__float__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__float__) and [`__complex__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__complex__) are not defined then corresponding built-in functions `int()`, `float()` and `complex()` fall back to `__index__()`.**

*(added bold)*

`a.__int__()` exists, so its return value is used instead.

```
>>> a.__int__
<method-wrapper '__int__' of MyClass object at 0x7f2c5f0f4ec8>
>>> a.__int__()
100
```

Comment: This is wrong. It's because the class is an int subclass.

Comment: This is verifiably not the answer (try overwriting `__int__`, it won't affect anything).

Comment: Huh, so the documentation for `object.index()` is wrong? It says *"Equivalent to `a.__index__()`"*, but evidently that's incorrect, it's more like `a if isinstance(a, int) else a.__index__()`.

Comment: *whenever Python needs to losslessly convert the numeric object to an integer object* - it's already an integer object so Python doesn't need to convert.

Comment: The answer is not just incorrect for CPython or any particular implementation. It's incorrect for Python regardless. In no case was it documented that `operator.index(obj)` will prefer `__int__` over `__index__`, the bold section refers to unrelated built-in functions (int, float, complex).